# Android DatePicker initialization doesn't work

Tags: android, datepicker

I have:

```
((DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.my_id)).init(2011, 1, 1, pickerListener);
```

And when I run this, I have nullPointerException.

pickerListener is created. And onDateChanged is empty.

What could solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `setContentView` before calling `findViewById`. Otherwise you will get Null from `findViewById`

For example, if `my_id` is defined in `main.xml`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
((DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.my_id)).init(2011, 1, 1, pickerListener);
```